# Insert counter in .map() for react jsx

Tags: reactjs

I need to map through two different arrays adding them as rows to a single table. To do this I am attempting to use a counter instead of index (since react requires a unique key per iteration). I can't use index for the key because I have to concatenate and that makes the indexes not unique per row. So instead, I am attempting with a counter but am getting stuck on how I should increment the number...

```
...
    {dateTable.categories.map((category, indexThree, categories) =>
      {
        let rowCounter = 0;
        const firstRows = category.firstRows.map((row, indexFour, firstRowsArr) =>
          <tr key={indexFour}>
            {indexFour === 0 ?
            <td>
                <h5>{category.name}</h5>
            </td> : <td />
            }
            <td>{row.valOne}</td>
            <td style={{backgroundColor: "#ffedbc"}}>{row.valTwo}</td>
            <td>{row.valThree}</td>
            <td>{row.valFour}</td>
          </tr>
        );
        const secondRows = category.secondRows.map((row, indexFive, secondRowsArr) =>
        <tr key={indexFive+rowCounter}>
          {indexFive === 0 && category.firstRows.length === 0 ?
          <td>
              <h5>{category.name}</h5>
          </td> : <td />
          }
          <td>{row.valOne}</td>
          <td>{row.valTwo}</td>
          <td>{row.valThree}</td>
          <td>{row.valFour}</td>
        </tr>
        );
        console.log("rowCounter", rowCounter);
        return firstRows.concat(secondRows);
      }
    )}
...
```

Comment: The key is a string. You can just use both indices joined with a separator. Or you can create a single flat array first and then map over that single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use

```
<tr key={rowCounter++}>
```

for both.

---

But if you are not going to use this for an arbitrary number of categories, you should just drop the counter and prepend a different string for each array, along with its index.

```
<tr key={`first-${indexFour}`}>
```

and

```
<tr key={`second-${indexFive}`}>
```

---

But the best would be if you had a unique key for reach row, so you could do

```
<tr key={row.someUniqueKey}>
```

Comment: Thx, this actually answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

you can add the firstArray length on the secondArray index, without counter

```
<tr key={indexFive + firstRows.length}>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I should have thought of that, but probably just need rest. Thanks so much!!!